# Knockout Components - Cannot apply bindings more than once

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components

I'm trying to create a page using knockout components, and I'm having some trouble trying to bind multiple components in a page if they aren't added at the same time. As far as I can see I have no way to directly access the viewmodel of the component, to bind it to the specific element.

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("component1"));
```

My problem is that, since I thus have to use the more general

```
ko.applyBindings()
```

if I add another component to the page at a later time, and want to bind it, I receive the "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element." error.

Is there any way for me to access a components view model and apply it directly?

```
$('body').append('<div id="compoent1" data-bind=\'component: { name:"someComponent"\}'></div>')
ko.applyBindings(viewModel/*How do I get this?*/, document.getElementById("component1"));
```

I've tried just using

```
ko.applyBindings(document.getElementById("component1"));
```

My explanations is perhaps somewhat hard to understand, here is pseudo code of what I am trying to do:

```
Add a knockout component
Apply bindings for the knockout component
.... some time later in my single page application
Add another knockout component
Apply bindings for the new knockout component
```

Comment: "if I add another component to the page at a later time" How are you adding the component? In a non-knockouty way (i.e. with jquery or similar)?

Comment: You're trying to use the _same_ view model? If it's in your code you can just have a reference to it - although there _is_ a way to get the view model with KO it'd be silly. Namely `ko.dataFor`.

Comment: Your best bet here is to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve), right now it's hard to tell quite what you're doing and, therefore, quite how we can help you make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you're probably trying to add a component using non-knockout methods.

Once you go knockout, it's better to keep everything in the knockout fold and to resist the temptation of falling back onto jQuery or straight DOM manipulation for the "quick win". It always bites you later... so:

```
 <foocomponent params="woo:'fwoo'"></foocomponent >
 <!-- ko if:someBooleanObservableThatChangesLater -->
     <myawesomecomponent params="choo:'boo'"></myawesomecomponent >
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Now we've "added" a second component by changing an observable in our root model (`someBooleanObservableThatChangesLater`). No re-binding required.

Your circumstances may be somewhat different to my rather simple example above, but hopefully the intent is clear. You can get similar behaviour by pushing items into an `observableArray` and using the `foreach` binding on it so that content gets added to/removed from the DOM whenever you change the `observableArray`. Once again, no second call to `applyBindings` is required.

Comment: Makes sense! I'm just starting out with knockout, so I'm still very much in the jQuery mindset I suppose. I'll try to use some booleans to add stuff. However, with multiple "sub-sites" in an SPA I figure one huge viewmodel will get very messy.

Comment: Yes. I've been stung by exactly that problem... however, it's easy to reduce clutter by segregating responsibilities in your view model by defining classes/factories that encapsulate portions of what would be a larger, monolithic viewmodel.